# Who broke your window?

Tags: mystery

One snowy night, you were sitting in your house sitting near a nice cozy fire. All of a sudden, a snowball came crashing through the window, destroying it. You hear voices of laughter and sounds of running and quickly look out your window to see 4 neighborhood kids who were all brothers running away. Their names were John Crimson, Mark Crimson, Paul Crimson, and Cody Crimson. You wake up the next morning to see a note under your door. It read:

> ? Crimson, he broke your window last night!

You, being a detective, knew exactly who you were going to interrogate about the incident the night before. Who are you going to interrogate?

Note: I was told this mystery last year, I’m not sure where it came from, good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the answer

> Mark Crimson

> Reason for that is "? Crimson" can be read as "Question Mark Crimson", so the note is saying to interrogate him.

Comment: Correct, the note said who to interrogate!